# Get Extras from video

Tags: android

I have been trying to get a list of the extras bundled with the native camera app
I want to take a video, save it and then keep the file path

```
Intent chooseCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(chooseCamera,cameraData);
```

Ive got this so far and I found a tutorial on getting the bitmap for a still image but not the video. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
cameraData=2;
Intent chooseCamera  = new  Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);   
startActivityForResult(chooseCamera, cameraData);  

@Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {   
        try{   
            if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){   
                if(requestCode==cameraData){   
                    path = data.getData().toString();   //VIDEO path 
                }   
            }   
        }catch(Exception e){   
            e.printStackTrace();   
        }   
    }
```